# Deleting old records while keeping a minimum number of records per parent

Tags: sql-server, delete-row, sql-delete

My question is similar to [sql statement to delete records older than XXX as long as there are more than YY rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210515/66169), but that question just deals with a single parent, I want to delete records for all parents in one go.

Consider this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Children
(
    ChildId int NOT NULL,
    ChildCreated datetime NOT NULL,
    ParentId int NOT NULL
)
```

This could be any parent-child relationship, so the names are generic.

I would like to delete all children that are older than a month, but need to keep a minimum number of children for each parent regardless of their age.

I tried some statements with nested SELECTs and GROUP BYs which gave me some results but none gave me the correct result set.

Because I am using SQL Server I came up with the following solution that works great:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ParentId ORDER BY ChildCreated DESC) 
  As RowNo, ChildCreated FROM Children
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNo > 10
AND RevisionCreated < DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GetDate())
```

The common table expression groups all children for each parent together and adds a continuous row number based on the creation order. The newest child for each parent has
a row number of 1, the tenth newest has 10. So I can just delete all records with a row
number greater 10 as long as they are also over a month old.

My question is, what if I have to do the same thing on a system where CTEs are not supported. What is the **ANSI SQL-92** solution for this problem?

Comment: As far as I am aware CTEs *are* valid in the ANSI SQL 99 standard. Perhaps you want a solution for a database that does *not* support the standard? (MySQL perhaps?)

Comment: @MarkByers I wasn't aware of CTEs being in SQL-99, yes I would be interested in a solution for systems where CTEs are not supported. I changed the question to ask for SQL-92.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on other responses, and the relative simplicity of my query I think I might be over simplifying the issue, but I am assuming since parentID is not nullable that it does not reference childID, In which case it can be achieved as simply as the below

```
DELETE  Children
FROM    Children a
WHERE   ChildCreated < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
AND     (   SELECT  COUNT(*)    -- NUMBER OF NEWER CHILDREN WITH THE SAME PARENT
            FROM    Children b
            WHERE   a.ParentID = b.ParentID
            AND (   a.ChildCreated < b.ChildCreated
                OR  (a.ChildCreated = b.ChildCreated AND a.ChildID > b.ChildID)
                )
        ) >= 10
```

Although this exact SQL may need tweaking depending on RDBMS, I don't know of any RDBMS where this principal cannot be applied.

Comment: This does not seem to work, because you exclude all children created after the cut-off date and only look at the old ones. Think about what your sub-query returns, maybe for the oldest child it returns 11, so it qualifies, but for the second oldest it returns 10 (because the oldest one is not younger than the second oldest) so, the second oldest does not qualify.

Comment: I've edited the answer slightly to change ">"  to ">=" after the subquery, and made allowances for 2 children of the same parent having the same timestamp. I don't fully understand your comment unless it is referring to the ">=" error I had made after the subquery so I don't know how to improve my answer. The query I have posted will delete children that are older than one month that below to a parent with at least 10 children new that it. As far as I can tell this was the criteria you needed? I am going to have put it down to me misunderstanding the question.

Comment: This one works and all three queries now delete the same set of records. Yours even works for duplicate ChildCreated values. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely a drag on performance but following statement

- adds a `rownumber`, restarting for each group, by using a subselect for each record on the count of childs of the same group.
- returns an in memory table containing `ChildId`'s with given rownumber.
- `JOIN` back to the original table on `ChildId`
- adds a `WHERE` clause where you can filter on given `rownumber` and/or additional columns from `Children`.
- uses the result in a `DELETE FROM` statement.

**SQL Statement**

```
DELETE FROM Children
FROM    Children c
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  ChildId
                  , ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
                      FROM   Children rn
                      WHERE  rn.ChildCreated < Children.ChildCreated
                             AND rn.ChildId = Children.ParentId
                      ) AS rn           
          FROM    Children
        ) rn ON rn.ChildId = c.ChildId          
WHERE   rn.rn > 10
        AND ChildCreated < DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GetDate())
```

Comment: Interesting, a few points: 1. the 'FROM children FROM Children c' syntax doesn't look right to me, I think you can remove the first 'FROM children' part. 2. You are comparing rn.ChildId with Children.ChildId which assumes the Ids are in sequence of creation, it would be safer to compare rn.ChildCreated with Children.ChildCreated. 3. Why the COALESCE, shouldn't it always be the ParentId which can't be NULL? Otherwise it seems to work but is indeed slow.

Comment: I tested this in practice which has slightly different requirements. The ChildCreated field is actually a LastModified field, so I can not rely on the order of the ChildId and have to compare the LastModified fields, the problem is that a parent may have two children with the same value in LastModified. If the 10th and 11th oldest children have the same LastModified value, none of them is included. But if you have unique Ids it should work.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - 1. The `DELETE FROM Children FROM` is valid syntax afaik. 2. You are right about comparing the ChildCreated dates. 3. Right on that to <g>.

Comment: sorry the Delete.. is fine, first thing I did was changing the DELETE to a SELECT and then it's invalid, my fault. Your current version works for unique 'ChildCreated' values except that I had to change 'rn.ChildCreated < Children.ChildCreated' to 'rn.ChildCreated > Children.ChildCreated'